# I am trying to Use Ajax With Spring Mvc in liferay.I Have a Jsp File and Controller Class.But The Controller class is not called

Tags: jquery, ajax, liferay

hi I am trying to Use Ajax with Spring Mvc Porltet In liferay.I Have a Jsp File and Controller Class.I want to insert a data in the form but my controller class is Not Called.So please Help Me to Solve this Problem.When I Click on submit My COntroller class is not called.

```
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayWindowState"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui" %>

<portlet:defineObjects/>
<portlet:resourceURL id="actionOneMethodURL" var="actionOneMethodURL">
</portlet:resourceURL>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function namet()
{


    alert("in the function");
    var name = document.getElementById('<portlet:namespace/>name').value;
    var age = document.getElementById('<portlet:namespace/>age').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('<portlet:namespace/>email').value;

    jQuery.ajax({
        url : "<%=actionOneMethodURL%>",
        datatype : 'POST',
        data : {
            reqname : name,
            reqage  : age,
            reqemail: email,
            },
        success : function(response)
            {

            },
        });

}
</script>

</head>
</html>
<body>
    <form  method="post" id='<portlet:namespace/>fm' name='<portlet:namespace/>fm'>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="name">Name:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input name="<portlet:namespace/>name" id="<portlet:namespace/>name" class="field-required" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="Age">Age:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input name="<portlet:namespace/>age" id="<portlet:namespace/>age" class="field-required" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="email">Email:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input name="<portlet:namespace/>email" id="<portlet:namespace/>email" class="field-required" type="text">

            </div>

        </div>
        <input class="btn btn-info" type="button" value="save" name="action" onclick="namet()">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="reset" value="Reset">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
Here Is my Jsp File...

package com.hrms;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.portlet.ActionRequest;
import javax.portlet.ActionResponse;
import javax.portlet.PortletConfig;
import javax.portlet.RenderRequest;
import javax.portlet.RenderResponse;
import javax.portlet.ResourceRequest;
import javax.portlet.ResourceResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.bind.annotation.ActionMapping;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.bind.annotation.RenderMapping;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.bind.annotation.ResourceMapping;

import com.hrms.model.HRMS;
import com.hrms.service.HRMSLocalServiceUtil;
import com.liferay.counter.service.CounterLocalServiceUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.ServletResponseUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ParamUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.StringPool;
import com.liferay.portal.service.ServiceContext;
import com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil;

@Controller(value = "HrmsController")
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
public class HrmsController {

    @RenderMapping
    public String handleRenderRequest(RenderRequest request,
            RenderResponse response, Model model) {
        return "view";
    }

    @ResourceMapping(value="actionOneMethodURL")
    public void actionOneMethodURL(ResourceRequest request,ResourceResponse response) throws SystemException, IOException {
        System.out.println("In the Method");
        int id = 0;

        id = (int) CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment(HrmsController.class.getName());
        String reqname = ParamUtil.getString(request, "reqname");
        String reqage = ParamUtil.getString(request, "reqage");
        String reqemail = ParamUtil.getString(request, "reqemail");

        HRMS hrms = null;
        hrms = HRMSLocalServiceUtil.createHRMS(id);
        hrms.setName(reqname);
        hrms.setAge(reqage);
        hrms.setEmail(reqemail);

        hrms = HRMSLocalServiceUtil.updateHRMS(hrms);

        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = PortalUtil.getHttpServletResponse(response);
        ServletResponseUtil.write(httpServletResponse, response.toString());
    }

}

and here is my Controller Class...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url : "<%=actionOneMethodURL%>",
        **datatype : 'POST',**
        data : {
            reqname : name,
            reqage  : age,
            reqemail: email,
            },
        success : function(response)
            {

            },
        });
```

Your code above[marked bold] seems erroneous.
datatype defines "the type of data that you're expecting back from the server".
Whereas type attribute defines method GET or POST for ajax call.

Please make that change.
Also make sure you have method in Controller with @ResourceMapping annotation to handle ajax resource url.

Comment: I do this change but still not working.. jQuery.ajax({
  url : "<%=actionOneMethodURL.toString()%>",
  type : 'POST',
  data : {
   name : name,
   age  : age,
   email: email,
   },
  });
}
</script>

Comment: do you have any method in controller with annotation @ResourceMapping ?

Comment: I described My Controller Class Code Below My Jsp Page Code.

Answer (score 0):

Change  **datatype : 'POST'** to  **type: 'GET'**

As Ajax POST is handled by processAction.

So change your 'type' to from 'POST' to 'GET'